# Is it possible to make a standalone OS X app from manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, export, mac-os-x, output, version-7

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a standalone app from a manipulate box.  I mean a small app that do exactly what the manipulate box is doing in Mathematica, but without Mathematica.  In other words, is it possible to export a Mathematica manipulate to a standalone app, in OS X ?

I guess the answer is a big NO.  Anyone confirm this ?

Comment: maybe [CDF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html) is the closest option.

Comment: I believe that my old version of Mathematica (v7) cannot do this.  But I don't care much about my version.  My question above is for any newer version.

Comment: While the CDF is your best option, it requires a hefty install package (560mb). You could `CloudDeploy` a manipulate, which works inside a browser; however, the Cloud is saddled with significant lag, as each computation makes a round-trip to the server.

Comment: There are some restrictions too: http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html

Comment: So must I conclude that it's currently not possible to export any manipulate box from Mathematica to a simple standalone app, in OS X ?  This would be an awesome feature !

Comment: While `CloudDeploy` is not available in V7 you can create test account on Mathematica Online (or whatever it's name is now) if you are an active user. Then you can CloudDeploy from there. It won't be the smoothest or not everything is working but the user only needs browser and your credit points. Tell me if that worked.